Apple Watch Series 9 cannot use precision finding to locate an AirTag
I have some AirTags and an iPhone 11, all of which use Ultra-Wideband 1. With my iPhone, I can find the AirTags, but not with the Apple Watch.
So, I wanted to know if the fact that the Series 9 has UWB2 prevents it from finding the AirTags.
This has frustrated me so much that I am considering downgrading to the Series 8.

This feature only works with second gen UWB chip, which the series 9 and iPhone 15 have. So you can find an iPhone 15 with your watch using precision finding. But I don't think any airtags have this second gen chip (yet in July 2024), and Apple only mentions this feature working to find an iPhone 15:

"Your iPhone. Lost and precisely found. Also enabled by the
second-generation Ultra Wideband chip, Precision Finding can direct
you to your iPhone by showing you its approximate distance and
direction.".... "Requires an iPhone and Apple Watch with second-generation
Ultra Wideband chip. Ultra Wideband availability varies by region."

https://www.apple.com/apple-watch-series-9/#footnote-2

Thank you. I will return the Series 9 and buy the Series 8, as it is essential for me to find the AirTags. Besides, the Series 9 added few worthwhile features.
